# Saving a file automatically from an hyperlink in the body of outlook mail

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook, automation

I'am trying to save a word document from an hyperlink in the body of outlookmail.

m is the mail item ;

```
try
            {
               string s;
               System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
                Word.Hyperlink wlink = null;
                if (m.GetInspector.IsWordMail())
                {
                    Word.Document oDoc = m.GetInspector.WordEditor;
                    Word.Hyperlinks links = oDoc.Hyperlinks;
                    for (int j = 1; j <=links.count(); j++)
                    {
                        object index = (object)j;
                        if (links.get_Item(ref index).Address.Contains("format=msw"))
                        {
                            wlink = links.get_Item(ref index);
                            s = wlink.Address;
                                wc.DownloadFile(s, AppSettings.Default.savefolderpath + filename + " Word.docx");
                                index = null;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

i am getting the following error :
The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found.   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.FoldersClass.get_Item(Object Index)

Comment: is there any other way to downlaod document using the hyperlinks from the mail

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the error is raised in that snippet of your code? It looks like you are accessing a folder by name and it does not exist: `MAPIFolder.Folders("I do not exist")`